# Remove Test Ad on admob

Tags: objective-c, xcode, admob, ads, interstitial

I implemented interstitial ads on xcode
but it says "Test Ad" on the top of ads
how can I remove the text or make it real?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With GADExtras you can specify additional parameters.
Add an extra with key "suppress_test_label" and value "1" to your request, to prevent the Test mode label showing on the simulator.

I needed this when generating screenshots automatically on the simulator.

Objective-C:

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
GADExtras *extras = [[GADExtras alloc] init];
extras.additionalParameters = @{@"suppress_test_label": @"1"};
[request registerAdNetworkExtras:extras];
```

Swift:

```
let request = GADRequest()
let extras = GADExtras()
extras.additionalParameters = ["suppress_test_label": "1"]
request.register(extras)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on the real device then you can comment out the deviceID code and then **test ad** tag will disappear in the real device.

```
testDevices={
                  [
                    // AdMobBanner.simulatorId,
                    // '15243612fa84c82f220222a8948087a86',
                  ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GADRequest` and it's subclasses, such as `DFPRequest`, has `testDevices` [property](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads). It contains a list of device id's where test ads are being shown instead of real ones.

Most likely, you don't need to do anything with it, because this array may include only `kGADSimulatorID` (to show ads in iOS Simulator) and other test devices from your organization. So a user who downloads the app from the App Store would see only real ads.

Also as Google points in [Test Ads documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads):

> It is important to enable test ads during development so that you can click on them without charging Google advertisers

But if you really-really want to disable test ads, you may set `testDevices` to `nil`, or wrap it in `#ifdef DEBUG`. For example:

```
DFPRequest* request = [DFPRequest request]; // or GADRequest
#if DEBUG
request.testDevices = @[kGADSimulatorID /*, and other test device IDs*/];
#else
request.testDevices = nil;
#endif
```